# Why has my wired internet connection become intermittent?

Tags: internet-connection

I have my laptop plugged in with an ethernet cable at work. It gives me internet.  Two weeks ago it started becoming intermittent.  At apparently random intervals I cannot load any more web pages. Firefox will try for a long time to load any pages, and in the end it says "server not found."  If I wait about five minutes, it will start working again.

It is not just firefox: Dropbox loses it's connection too.

The network manager gives me no errors or complaints.  I have disabled wireless, thinking that my personal hotspot might be interfering with it.

My colleague has a different ethernet cable plugged into her computer, and she has no such problems with her internet connection. I used her cable with my laptop, but the problem remained.

I have dual boot.  I tested the connection with Windows 7, and with substantial browsing the problem didn't arise.  It seems likely that there's something fishy going on with my Ubuntu installation.  I may test with Windows again, just to make sure.

I updated Ubuntu today.

What can I do to find the cause of this problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network I am on is administrated poorly.  I used to get a lot of IP address conflicts.  Knowing this to be the case, I tried spoofing my MAC address.  I used macchanger.

I have now been using the internet for an hour without any timeouts or slowness.  It looks like this fixed it.